# How to login on a page and read url content from it?

Tags: c++, c, curl

I have a problem.
I wanted to login e.g. in ogame and read the url source code from it.
But everytime I start my code, my file returns the login page and not the second page after login.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

FILE *fptr;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{

    fptr = fopen("ogametest.html", "w");
    fputs((const char*)contents, (FILE*)fptr);
    fclose (fptr);
        //printf("%s", (char *) contents);
  return size * nmemb;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  char strlist[16000]="";
  char* str= &strlist[0];

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://de.ogame.gameforge.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "usernameLogin=myLogin&passwordLogin=myPassw&serverLogin=s146-de.ogame.gameforge.com");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    //curl_easy_reset(curl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://s146-de.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=overview&relogin=1");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, str);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    fptr = fopen("ogametest.html", "r");
    fgets(str, 16000, fptr);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

It would be fine if you can help me.

Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. The url is wrong for login. The right url is "https://de.ogame.gameforge.com/main/login"
2. The post message is not the right format.
3. You need to handle the cookies. The cookies are used to save the login session. Without the cookies you'll be redirected to main page everytime you make any request at ogame.

Here is some curl code that works to login ogame

```
CURL* curl;
//Local initializing of curl object
curl = curl_easy_init();

//Defining parameters
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //print html header request/responses in console
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);//Follow redirects
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://de.ogame.gameforge.com/main/login");//Url
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");//Save cookies here
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");//Load cookies here
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "kid=&login=my%40email.here&pass=mypassword&uni=s148-de.ogame.gameforge.com");//Post message
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);//html code response function
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30");//Setting agent. Just do this

//Executing curl object
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

where

```
string htmlcode;
size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up){
for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
{
    htmldata.push_back(buf[c]);
}
return size*nmemb;}
```

is globally defined. So in this code the html code will be store in the string htmlcode.

Now the "my%40email.here" should be changed to your email. The %40 is @. "mypassword" should be changed to your password. The "s148-de.ogame.gameforge.com" depends the universe you play on. 148 is Virgo.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but I suggest you use a program to intercept the html requests/responses. In chrome you can go to DevTools Overview (shortcut f12). Under network you can track the exchange between the browser and server, which you can then try to mimic.